# Twisted $AdS_2 \times S^2$: Want a Coordinate Transformation that Makes Metric Diagonal.

Tags: physics, products, general-relativity, semi-riemannian-geometry

I already asked this question [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/342051/definition-of-warped-and-twisted-geometries) at mathoverflow but now that it seems to be clearer that the definition of a twisted product given below is indeed the one meant in the overview paper, the questions fits here better:

In the paper [Multiply Twisted Products](https://arxiv.org/abs/1207.0199v1) by Yong Wang, general definitions for so called *warped* and *twisted* products are given:

A **(singly) warped product** $B \times_b F$ of two pseudo-Riemannian manifolds $\left(B\,,g_B\right)$ and $\left(F\,,g_F\right)$ with a smooth function $b\,:\,B \to \left(0\,, \infty \right)$ is the product manifold $B \times F$ with the metric tensor $g = g_B \oplus b^2 g_F$. We call $\left(B\,,g_B\right)$ the **base** manifold, $\left(F\,,g_F\right)$ the **fiber** manifold and $b$ the warping function.

A **twisted product** $\left(M\,,g\right)$ is a product manifold $M = B \times_b F$, with a smooth function $b\,:\,B \times F \to \left(0\,, \infty \right)$ and the metric tensor $g = g_B \oplus b^2 g_F$.

It seems that those are the definitions meant in this [overview paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1203.3561) about the Kerr/CFT correspondence about the following metric

\begin{align}
  \mathrm{d}s^2 = J\left(1+\cos^2\theta\right)\left[-r^2dt^2 + \frac{dr^2}{r^2} + d\theta^2 \right] + \frac{4 \sin^2\theta}{1+\cos^2\theta} \left(d\phi + rdt\right)^2\,,
\end{align}

which is supposed to be a " warped and twisted product of $AdS_2 \times S^2$ " (J is just scaling the metric). I think the author just meant twisted, because in the above definitions the twisted productis the generalization of the warped product. Unfortunately I can't neither make out the above metric to be $AdS_2 \times S^2$, nor that it is for $\theta = \frac{\pi}{2}$ a "twisted product of $AdS_2$ and a circle of constant radius" (as [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9905099) suggests), as the suggested geometry should not have off-diagonal terms like $\mathrm{d}\phi \mathrm{d}t$ in the metric. For clarity, the metric of $AdS_2$ in Poincare coordinates is
\begin{align}
    \label{eq:poincarepatch}
    ds^2 =  - r^2dt^2 + \frac{dr^2}{r^2}\,,
\end{align}
where we set the curvature constant to $1$ to match the above expression.

How is the above twisted $AdS_2 \times S^2$? The coordinate transformation would have to get rid of the off-diagonal term $\mathrm{d}t\mathrm{d}\phi$.

Is there at least a theorem that ensures the existence of such a coordinate transformation?